# Question about Schwarz Reflexion Principle Proof from Stein's complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My question is how I can show that F extends continuously up to $I$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $\Omega^-$ that converges to a point $z$ in $I$. Then we also have $\overline{z_n} \to \overline{z}$. Thus $$F(z_n) = \overline{f(\overline{z_n})} \to \overline{f(\overline{z})} = \overline{f(z)} = f(z).$$

Comment: But why he says that from fact that $\overline{f(x)} = f(x)$ on $I$ implies that $F$ extends continuously up to $I$?

Comment: @MathLearner Updated my answer.